# How to change icon of an webapp created with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, icons, 18.04

I've added Vysor app to my dock, I would like to change the icon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find a `.desktop` file associated to the webapp in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. Open the file with a text editor and change the line `Icon=...` to

```
Icon=/full/path/to/your/preferred/image
```